# How can I add same code to many object

Tags: .net, textbox

I have three textBoxes in Visual Basic 2010. If the user clicks on a textBox I want to clear the text, but I don't want to copy paste the code for all of the textBoxes. I want the same behavior on all three textBoxes.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please update the post with your code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the same event handler code for multiple TexBoxes, for example

```
Private Sub TextBox_click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Click, TextBox2.Click, TextBox3.Click

   CType(sender, TextBox).Text = ""

End Sub
```

This example is in VB.NET, but in C# it would be similar.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance would be a good place to look into, have one central textbox class, that your other textboxes are inherited from

You could also make a function that accepted a textbox as one of its arguments, and have it work with all of them

Or, you could make a class to wrap around the textbox class that includes the distinctions between them via a function in your wrapper class